# How is the Hokuyo UST 10lx LIDAR connected?

Tags: ros, lidar, jetson-tk1

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two cables -  the ethernet and the a power cable. The power cable as 6 wires out of which two go to the power source of 12 V. Where do the other four wires go? What are they connected to? The ethernet cable was connected to a Jetson TK1 through a ethernet to USB connector.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257525/how-is-the-hokuyo-ust-10lx-lidar-connected?/) by [frixbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/29768/frixbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't have enough points to post a picture, but it's on page 5 of this specification manual.

https://www.hokuyo-aut.jp/02sensor/07scanner/download/UST-10LX_spec_en.pdf

---

Originally posted by [corcorant](https://answers.ros.org/users/29721/corcorant/) with karma: 67 on 2017-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [frixbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/29768/frixbot/) on 2017-03-22**:
Hello,thank you for your answer. I saw that but I'm still confused as to what those wires are connected to. What is the I/O power source? Where is the IP reset?